# C# coupled classes - strongly typed structure design

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have a following class structure:

```
interface IA
{
    List<IB> Children { get; }
}

interface IB
{
    IA Parent { get; }
    List<IC> Children { get; }
}

interface IC
{
    IB Parent { get; }
    List<ID> Children { get; }
}

interface ID
{
    IC Parent { get; }
}
```

Classes implementing those interfaces are closely coupled - we have sets of classes **XA : A, XB : B, XC : C, XD : D**.
What I would like to achieve is knowing the exact type of the parent and children at compile time.

Generics are the obvious way, but the implementation looks awful to me:

```
interface IA<TA, TB, TC, TD>
    where TA : IA
    where TB : IB
    where TC : IC
    where TD : ID
{
    List<TB> Children { get; }
}

interface IB<TA, TB, TC, TD>
    where TA : IA
    where TB : IB
    where TC : IC
    where TD : ID
{
    TA Parent { get; }
    List<TC> Children { get; }
}

interface IC<TA, TB, TC, TD>
    where TA : IA
    where TB : IB
    where TC : IC
    where TD : ID
{
    TB Parent { get; }
    List<TD> Children { get; }
}

interface ID<TA, TB, TC, TD>
    where TA : IA
    where TB : IB
    where TC : IC
    where TD : ID
{
    TC Parent { get; }
}
```

At the moment it is implemented by casting in runtime, which I consider incorrect. It's like this:

```
class XA : IA
{
    //...
}

class XB : IB
{
    //...
    public XA StronglyTypedParent { get { return (XA) this.Parent; } }
}
```

How should it be done? Is there a better way to achieve this? Maybe there exists a structural pattern for solving such problem? Any suggestions would be most welcome. Thank you.

**Edit**

It looks that my description of the problem is not clear enough. Let's consider a real-world example:

The IA, IB, IC, ID interfaces correspond to some calculations performed for different periods of time - let's rename them to **IYearCalculation, IMonthCalculation, IWeekCalculation, IDayCalculation**.

We perform different calculations but all of them have the same structure - like:

```
class YearCalculationA : IYearCalculation
class MonthCalculationA : IMonthCalculation
class WeekCalculationA : IWeekCalculation
class DayCalculationA : IDayCalculation
```

And then, by

> knowing the exact type of the parent and children at compile time.

I mean, for instance, within the **DayCalculationA** class, knowing the exact type of the corresponding year calculation (which is **YearCalculationA** - not just **IYearCalculation**).

I also need to resolve previous calculation on the same level (example: previous **day** calculation from **DayCalculationA**), which is of the same type - but without generics I need to perform a runtime cast.

Comment: How does the generics tell you the exact type at compile time? I don't think you can find a pattern which tells you to code to an implementation and not an abstraction, like you try to do.

Comment: If you need to know the exact type at runtime, then inheritance is the wrong solution.

Comment: I also don't seem to understand what's making the object typing ambiguous or why you'd need to cast these types, can you elaborate somehow what the issue is?

Comment: This is a little bit... abstract.  But whenever I have a problem with inheritance, I rewrite for composition.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to know the concrete types?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I edited the question to make the problem clearer. I don't know how to rewrite this code to eliminate my difficulties.

Comment: Is it possible to put calculation in some virtual method applicable for all classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# does not support return type variance, so this is a pretty common problem. The way I solve it when I need to is explicitly implementing the interface:

```
class XA : IA
{
    //...
}

class XB : IB
{
    private readonly XA parent;

    public XA Parent { get { return parent; } }
    IA IB.Parent { get { return Parent; } } //XA is implicitly convertible to IA so no ugly castings needed
}
```

Now any expressión like `xB.Parent` will be typed `XA` while expressions like `iB.Parent` will be typed `IA`. You get the best of both worlds.

Comment: Thanks, this might be very useful (though it must be repeated for every class implementing any of the specified interfaces).

Comment: @kra yes, that is a drawback, but there isn't a way around it really because creating a base implementation to avoid boilerplate code simply puts you right back in square one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via reflection:

```
var sampleClassName = XB.StronglyTypedParent.GetType().FullName;

var newClassInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(sampleClassName));
```

But when you are getting to the point of doing this, you need to be asking yourself:

"Is this really the right approach?"

Clever tricks like this make the code less maintainable and harder to understand for new developers

Answer (score 0):

Generics commonly used when some algorithm use abstractions and no need to know every details of entities, if you concrete describe every level you no need to use generics, just write four classes.

Need to know your task more detail to advice, but in case your task is about to traverse your tree or something abstract operations, your structure could be like this:

```
    interface INode<TParentType, TChildType>: IRoot<TChildType>, ILeaf<TParentType>
    {
    }

    interface IRoot<TChildType>
    {
        List<TChildType> Children { get; }            
    }

    interface ILeaf<TParentType>
    {
        TParentType Parent { get; }            
    }

    class FirstLevel : IRoot<SecondLevel> 
    {
        public List<SecondLevel> Children { get; set; }
    }

    class SecondLevel : INode<FirstLevel, ThirdLevel>
    {
        public List<ThirdLevel> Children { get; set; }

        public FirstLevel Parent { get; set; }
    }

    class ThirdLevel : INode<SecondLevel, FourthLevel>
    {
        public List<FourthLevel> Children { get; set; }

        public SecondLevel Parent { get; set; }
    }

    class FourthLevel : ILeaf<ThirdLevel>
    {
        public ThirdLevel Parent { get; set; }
    }
```

Please describe what operations will you do with this structure, how it will be loaded, modified and processed?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added some explanation to the original post. The structure is constructed from the bottom level (leaves).